# MVC ASP.NET Share Controller Between Two Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two different views that share the functionality of a single controller. The only difference is that when an action is called from the view, the controller needs to return the proper view.

How should I go about implementing such a thing?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you call the controller method? How do you distinguish the view? Why do you not have separate methods?

Comment: By "action is called from the view" do you really mean "action is called from the browser"? Views do not call into controller methods (excluding `RenderAction`).

Comment: How many views do you have. Is it three ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use model property at returning time from controller to view within if statements....
 After Your Code Executed in controller..

```
Yourmodel modelObj= new Yourmodel ();
.// first condition for first view
.
.
modelObj.Message="1" //for first view code
.
if(modelObj.Message=="1")
{
return redirectToAction("yourView","Controller");
}
else
{
 return redirectToAction("yourView-2","Controller");
}
```